# import request command in python 2.7.12 yeilding requests dependency warning

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I am new to python and I am trying to learn webscraping. I use Linux mint 18.2 and python version is as given in subject line. I have run `pip install requests` and subsequent `pip install request --upgrade` (all ran successfully). However, I am receiving below error while trying to import requests library:

`import requests`

> Warning (from warnings module):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/**init**.py", line 80
>       RequestsDependencyWarning) RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.13.1) or chardet (2.3.0) doesn't match a supported version!
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       import requests   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/**init**.py", line
>   90, in 
>       from urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning ImportError: cannot import name DependencyWarning

Comment: go into "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/init.py" around line 60 and 68 it will tell you which version of `urllib3` and `chardet` you need for `requests`